# Display Toast for a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast

I'm learning about **BroadcastReceiver**.

I would like display Toast message when SDcard is mounted or unmounted.

I followed few example provided on SO and wrote below code. However, when I mount/unmount SDCARD (Settings->Unmount SDCard), message "Hello there" is not displayed.

Thanks for any help.

```
<receiver
    android:name="MountReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MountReceiver(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive
            (Context context, Intent intent) {
        // react to the event
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this
                , "Hello there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please let me know the reason for downvote. So that I can avoid that mistake hereafter thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please check your Manifest file

```
<receiver
    android:name="<package>.MountReceiver"">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Rename `MainActivity.java` to `MountReceiver.java`

Update your code in `MountReceiver.java`

```
public class MountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // react to the event
       Toast.makeText(context, "Hello there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Feel free let me know your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive
        (Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Use application context
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed "MainActivity.this" to "context" as suggested, but its still not working.

Comment: Try putting a log and seeing if onReceive is ever getting called. If not, post your intent.

Comment: Thanks, will try and add logs and see if its get invoked. my Intent? Are you referring to code?  I have only "intent-filter" as mentioned in above manifest file. If you are not referring to code, I'm learning app development, want to learn broadcast receiver for any action first statically and then dynamically.

Comment: Added log, onReceive itself is not getting called. Do I need provide receiver's android:name differently like absolute path?

Comment: There are many reasons why the receiver is not going off, you should try to narrow them down.

Comment: I tried virtually whole day, tested broadcast receivers for "BLUETOOTH, BOOT_COMPLETE, sms received and wifi state and nothing worked! " Something definitely wrong with my moto-e? But I can see other installed apps working fine. (adb shell dumpsys package)

Comment: Not sure but you might want to post a question with more focus on getting SMS to trigger a receiver rather than showing a toast.

Comment: Thanks for help. After almost banging my head for more than 24 hrs. Found a the answer, I was using <receiver> outside <application> tag in manifest xml. Stupid,stupid me !

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on commenting section, I was so stupid to use `<receiver>` tag outside `<application>`. Somehow, I failed to realize that for more than 24 hrs. I hope this helps someone who is completely newbie like me, in future.